# How can I bypass the JavaFX's TableView "placeholder"?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

JavaFX's `TableView` has a [placeholder](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#placeholderProperty) property that is basically a `Node` that gets displayed in the `TableView` whenever it is empty.  If this property is set to null (its default value), it appears as a `Label` or some other text based `Node` that says "There is no content in the table."

But if there are any rows of data in the table, then the placeholder `Node` disappears and the entire vertical space in the `TableView` gets filled with rows, including empty rows if there isn't enough data to fill the whole table.

These empty rows are what I want, *even when the table is empty*.  In other words, I don't want to use the placeholder at all.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

I'd rather not do something kludgey like put a empty-looking row in the `TableView` whenever it's supposed to be actually empty.

Comment: +1 I'm looking for a way to do this too. In coding it out, you can manually set the placeHolder, i've usually set it to an image: `table.setPlaceholder(new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("someImage.png"))));` But i'd like to have it just display empty rows... also a way to do it in FXML would be handy

Comment: Feature request in the JavaFX issue tracker: [RT-31086 Don't force me to use the default 'placeholder' in an empty TableView](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31086).

Comment: the bug coordinates in openjdk rep: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090949 - still not solved in fx9/10

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for javafx8. It makes use of the non-public api, but it uses no reflection (luckly). Basically you need to set (or replace) the skin of the TableView and return a non-zero value in the method `getItemCount()`. Like so:

```
(TableView)t.setSkin(new TableViewSkin<Object>(t)
    {
        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            int r = super.getItemCount();
            return r == 0 ? 1 : r;
        }
    });
```

This method can also be used to add an extra row at the bottom of your last item (for if you want to include an add button for example). Basically return always one higher than the actual item-count.

Eventhough this is an old question, hopefully this was helpfull to someone.

Comment: verified that this looks fine in fx8 - the glitch I noticed is fx9 only. +1 for a simple solution :)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I didn't want the blank table with placeholder. This is the simplest solution I could find. Great job.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the [old issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090949) is still not fixed in fx9 nor later versions up and including fx18.

The original hack of the skin (see below the horizontal line) for fx9 seems to still be working in fx18. Though can be slightly improved since fx12 introduced access to the flow and tableHeaderRow.

While trying to adjust it to newer api, I came up with a - **just as dirty** and untested - approach. The idea is to override the actual layout method, that is the method that's called when laying out individual children of the table, watch out for the placeholder and replace it with the flow:

```
public class NoPlaceHolderSkin<T> extends TableViewSkin<T> {

    public NoPlaceHolderSkin(TableView<T> control) {
        super(control);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutInArea(Node child, double areaX, double areaY, double areaWidth,
            double areaHeight, double areaBaselineOffset, HPos halignment, VPos valignment) {
        if (child.getStyleClass().contains("placeholder")) {
            child.setVisible(false);
            child = getVirtualFlow();
            child.setVisible(true);
        }
        super.layoutInArea(child, areaX, areaY, areaWidth, areaHeight, areaBaselineOffset, halignment, valignment);
    }
}
```

---

So revisited the hacks in the context of fx9. There had been changes, good and bad ones:

- Skins moved into a public package which now allows to subclass them without accessing hidden classes (good)
- the move [introduced a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187379) which doesn't allow to install a custom VirtualFlow (fixed in fx10)
- reflective access to hidden members will be strongly disallowed (read: not possible) sometime in future

While digging, I noticed ever so slight glitches with the hacks (note: I did not run them against fx8, so these might be due differences in fx8 vs fx9!)

- the forced in-/visibility of placeholder/flow worked fine except when starting up with an empty table (placeholder was shown) and enlarging the table while empty (the "new" region looks empty)
- faking the itemCount to not-empty lets the rows dissappear on pressing navigation keys (which probably is not a big problem because users tend to not navigate an empty table) - this is definitely introduced in fx9, working fine in fx8

So I decided to go with the visibility enforcement: the reason for the slight glitches is that layoutChildren doesn't layout the flow if it thinks the placeholder is visible. That's handled by including the flow in the layout if super didn't.

The custom skin:

```
/**
 * TableViewSkin that doesn't show the placeholder.
 * The basic trick is keep the placeholder/flow in-/visible at all 
 * times (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27543830/203657).
 * <p> 
 * 
 * Updated for fx9 plus ensure to update the layout of the flow as
 * needed.
 * 
 * @author Jeanette Winzenburg, Berlin
 */
public class NoPlaceHolderTableViewSkin<T> extends TableViewSkin<T>{

    private VirtualFlow<?> flowAlias;
    private TableHeaderRow headerAlias;
    private Parent placeholderRegionAlias;
    private ChangeListener<Boolean> visibleListener = (src, ov, nv) -> visibleChanged(nv);
    private ListChangeListener<Node> childrenListener = c -> childrenChanged(c);
    
    /**
     * Instantiates the skin.
     * @param table the table to skin.
     */
    public NoPlaceHolderTableViewSkin(TableView<T> table) {
        super(table);
        flowAlias = (VirtualFlow<?>) table.lookup(".virtual-flow");
        headerAlias = (TableHeaderRow) table.lookup(".column-header-background");
        
        // startet with a not-empty list, placeholder not yet instantiatet
        // so add alistener to the children until it will be added
        if (!installPlaceholderRegion(getChildren())) {
            installChildrenListener();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Searches the given list for a Parent with style class "placeholder" and
     * wires its visibility handling if found.
     * @param addedSubList
     * @return true if placeholder found and installed, false otherwise.
     */
    protected boolean installPlaceholderRegion(
            List<? extends Node> addedSubList) {
        if (placeholderRegionAlias !=  null) 
            throw new IllegalStateException("placeholder must not be installed more than once");
        List<Node> parents = addedSubList.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getStyleClass().contains("placeholder"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (!parents.isEmpty()) {
            placeholderRegionAlias = (Parent) parents.get(0);
            placeholderRegionAlias.visibleProperty().addListener(visibleListener);
            visibleChanged(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    protected void visibleChanged(Boolean nv) {
        if (nv) {
            flowAlias.setVisible(true);
            placeholderRegionAlias.setVisible(false);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Layout of flow unconditionally.
     * 
     */
    protected void layoutFlow(double x, double y, double width,
            double height) {
        // super didn't layout the flow if empty- do it now
        final double baselineOffset = getSkinnable().getLayoutBounds().getHeight() / 2;
        double headerHeight = headerAlias.getHeight();
        y += headerHeight;
        double flowHeight = Math.floor(height - headerHeight);
        layoutInArea(flowAlias, x, y,
                width, flowHeight,
                baselineOffset, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }


    /**
     * Returns a boolean indicating whether the flow should be layout.
     * This implementation returns true if table is empty.
     * @return
     */
    protected boolean shouldLayoutFlow() {
        return getItemCount() == 0;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc} <p>
     * 
     * Overridden to layout the flow always.
     */
    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double width,
            double height) {
        super.layoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
        if (shouldLayoutFlow()) {
            layoutFlow(x, y, width, height);
            
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listener callback from children modifications.
     * Meant to find the placeholder when it is added.
     * This implementation passes all added sublists to 
     * hasPlaceHolderRegion for search and install the 
     * placeholder. Removes itself as listener if installed.
     * 
     * @param c the change 
     */
    protected void childrenChanged(Change<? extends Node> c) {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                if (installPlaceholderRegion(c.getAddedSubList())) {
                    uninstallChildrenListener();
                    return;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Installs a ListChangeListener on the children which calls
     * childrenChanged on receiving change notification. 
     * 
     */
    protected void installChildrenListener() {
        getChildren().addListener(childrenListener);
    }
    
    /**
     * Uninstalls a ListChangeListener on the children:
     */
    protected void uninstallChildrenListener() {
        getChildren().removeListener(childrenListener);
    }
    
    
}
```

Usage example:

```
public class EmptyPlaceholdersInSkin extends Application {

    private Parent createContent() {
        // initially populated
        //TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>(Person.persons()) {
        // initially empty
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>() {

            @Override
            protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
                return new NoPlaceHolderTableViewSkin<>(this);
            }
            
        };
        TableColumn<Person, String> first = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        first.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        
        table.getColumns().addAll(first);
        
        Button clear = new Button("clear");
        clear.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().clear());
        clear.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(table.getItems()));
        Button fill = new Button("populate");
        fill.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().setAll(Person.persons()));
        fill.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isNotEmpty(table.getItems()));
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(table);
        pane.setBottom(new HBox(10, clear, fill));
        return pane;
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(EmptyPlaceholdersInSkin.class.getName());

}
```

Comment: The 'row disapearing on arrow navigation' when faking the item count has to be a fx9/fx10 bug only, as I cannot reproduce it in fx8. Anyways, a nice overview about this problem/bug!

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution. It is definitely not nice, since it is accessing the API in a not wanted way, and I'm probably also making undesired use of the visibleProperty, but here you go:

You can try to hack the TableViewSkin. Basically do this to retrieve a hacked Skin:

```
public class ModifiedTableView<E> extends TableView<E> {
    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        final TableViewSkin<E> skin = new TableViewSkin<E>(this) {
          // override method here
        }
        // modifiy skin here
        return skin;
   }
}
```

For the TableViewSkin you then need to override following method:

```
@Override
protected VirtualFlow<TableRow<E>> createVirtualFlow() {
    final VirtualFlow<TableRow<E>> flow = new VirtualFlow<TableRow<E>>();
    // make the 'scroll-region' always visible:
    flow.visibleProperty().addListener((invalidation) -> {
        flow.setVisible(true);
    });
    return flow;
}
```

And for the skin using reflection stop showing the placeholder:

```
final Field privateFieldPlaceholderRegion = TableViewSkinBase.class.getDeclaredField("placeholderRegion");
privateFieldPlaceholderRegion.setAccessible(true);
final StackPane placeholderRegion = (StackPane) privateFieldPlaceholderRegion.get(skin);

// make the 'placeholder' never visible:
placeholderRegion.visibleProperty().addListener((invalidation) -> {
    placeholderRegion.setVisible(false);
});
```

Maybe you can change the visibility of the flow in the same method to make the code shorter... But I think you get the concept

Answer (score 2):

If any one is still looking for an alternate solution apart from what others had provided, below is the one which I worked with. As far as to me, this is the most simpliest approach I can go with (no custom skins, no API tweaking &  no heavy controls like ListView).

Set a StackPane with a customized CSS that resembles alternate row coloring.

```
StackPane placeHolder = new StackPane();
placeHolder.setStyle("-fx-background-color:linear-gradient(from 50px 14px to 50px 40px , repeat, #e8e8e8 49% , #f7f7f7 12% );");
tableView.setPlaceholder(placeHolder);
```

Below is the quick reference for implementation. The left table is with data and the right table is without data showing customized placeholder.

[image]

If your are specific with showing the column lines as well, you can follow the @Shreyas Dave approach of building a HBox of the StackPane(s) with border implementation.

```
HBox placeHolder = new HBox();
tableView.getColumns().forEach(tc->{
    StackPane colHolder = new StackPane();
    colHolder.getStyleClass().add("table-view-place-holder");
    colHolder.prefWidthProperty().bind(tc.widthProperty());
    placeHolder.getChildren().add(colHolder);
});
tableView.setPlaceholder(placeHolder);
```

And the CSS implementation is as below:

```
.table-view-place-holder{
  -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(from 50px 14px to 50px 40px , repeat, #232A2D 49% , #3D4549 12% );
  -fx-border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  -fx-border-color: linear-gradient(from 50px 14px to 50px 40px , repeat, #3D4549 49% , #232a2d 12% );
}
```

I have a requirement of having contrast border color to row background. I can easily acheive that with the above approach for having border color to my placeholder columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tricky way to perform your task,

```
    HBox box = new HBox();
    box.setDisable(true);
    for (TableColumn column : patientsTable.getColumns()) {
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().add("");
        listView.setPrefWidth(column.getWidth());
        box.getChildren().add(listView);
    }

    tableView.setPlaceholder(box);
```

Comment: Ha! That's sneaky.  Unfortunately, it doesn't quite look "right" in my table, which has a lot of resizable columns.  For a simple table with static columns, this could work, though.