# How to display a table without content?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working with JavaFX 2.2. Now I met a problem when using tableView.
I need to display a table without content, but when I use tableView.setItems(null), it just did not display anthing but "no content".

What I need is a table still has rows and columns(but empty).
Is there a good solution?

Comment: Related: [How can I bypass the JavaFX's TableView “placeholder”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992631/how-can-i-bypass-the-javafxs-tableview-placeholder)

Comment: Actually I set a row with null data, displaying nothing, but still has some effect like the chosen row. Maybe, I can edit the css file to perfect it. Thanks for your help.