# How to keep Grid Lines in empty TableView Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, grid, tableview, placeholder

I'm using javaFX and My problem is I want to keep grid lines traced even if there is no item on the TableView as shown on this image.
[The result i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1rsV.jpg)
but I get no success the TableView still display the placeholder if it is empty as shown:
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWDvc.jpg)

Comment: Not tested, but try `tableView.setPlaceholder(null);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bypass the JavaFX's TableView "placeholder"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992631/how-can-i-bypass-the-javafxs-tableview-placeholder)

Comment: @James_D Unfortunately setting the placeholder to `null` won't help. `TableViewSkinBase#updatePlaceholderRegionVisibility` sets the placeholder to standard values if it is `null`.

Comment: As mentioned on the duplicate question, there exists an enhancement request for this problem: [Don't force me to use the default 'placeholder' in an empty TableView](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090949).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around to achieve the wanted result :

- Add an empty row to the table
- Add the first element
- Remove the empty row